# What exactly is 'JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme' and 'JwtBearerDefaults' for?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api

What exactly is the call JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme and JwtBearerDefaults for?

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidIssuer = tokenOptions.Issuer,
        ValidAudience = tokenOptions.Audience,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = SecurityKeyHelper.CreateSecurityKey(tokenOptions.SecurityKey)
    };
});
```

Comment: Have you read the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbearerdefaults?view=aspnetcore-6.0)?

Comment: @devlincarnate I've read it, but I wanted to ask in case a more descriptive answer might come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` is a constant with the value "Bearer". This is just text that is similar in intent to the authentication provider.

When you call `AddAuthentication`, you need to provide the *default* authentication provider. Providers are named. By default `AddJwtBearer` will create an authentication provider with the name, yep you guessed it, `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`.

You *could* ignore the `JwtBearerDefaults` class altogether if you'd like, this is personal preference. Pass whatever string you want to `AddAuthentication`, then use the overload of `AddJwtBearer` that takes a string and an Action to customize the provider's name.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("MyCoolAuthProvider")
.AddJwtBearer("MyCoolAuthProvider", options => {
    //...
});
```

In the end, why do people use the `JwtBearerDefaults` class? Same reason you name your `for` loop variable `i`. It's what the documentation suggests, and everyone else does it. At least if it's a constant, you can't typo the value.